# Django connection error - django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: django, postgresql

My Django project fails to connect to postgres database.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication
> failed for user "postgres"

The settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    }
}
```

The `pg_hba.conf` file contents:

[image]

Before, the 'TRUSTED' method was set to 'PEER' by default. By it wasn't working that way. So I changed it to TRUSTED, ran `systemctl restart postgresql`, and it isn't working now either.

I know that postgres password is empty by default, so I tried the following:

```
sudo -u postgres psql

postgres=# ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

The output was `ALTER ROLE`.
But the error from Django still persists.

I ran out of ideas. Any hints ?

I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Look in the database server's log file to see what the full text of the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use ALTER ROLE instead of alter USER, as described in the docs. But since the response is ALTER ROLE, both might work.

Otherwise, you can try to login directly into the user

```
sudo psql -d myproject -U myprojectuser
```

Another option might be to check if a new user would work. I know the error says password authentication but have you granted privileges to the user?

```
CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET timezone TO 'UTC';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
```

Commands were taken from [the digitalocean ubuntu & django & posgres setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify the host as '127.0.0.1', you will not match either the 'peer' or the 'trust' lines which only apply to local sockets, not TCP connection.  But rather the `127.0.0.1/32 md5` line.

Setting the users password should have worked.  Look in the server's log file for more detailed reasons it did not.